# IntegrityError In Django admin

Tags: django-models, django-admin, integrity

**Can't modify the database with the Django admin**
whatever i make changes in the database on the admin website, it appears this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/tech/exercice/add/

Django Version: 4.0.4
Python Version: 3.10.11
Installed Applications:
['tech',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 267, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1885, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1744, in changeform_view
    with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 255, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 291, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 266, in _commit
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 267, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/tech/exercice/add/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Exercice(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    response = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    level = models.IntegerField(blank=False)


    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id" : self.id,
            "question" : self.question,
            "response" : self.response,
            "level" : self.level
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.question[:10]}..."
```

(i already registred the two models in the admin.py)

i deleted the database and remigrate it and nothing added,
there's no ForeignKey in my models as you see but it appears that
**FOREIGN KEY constraint failed**